# How to re-setup Database configurations in Icinga2 server?

Tags: mysql, monitoring, icinga2, icingaweb2

I am using ubuntu 16.04 and mysql DB ,i configured DB for icinga2 server and i created separate user in database.
somedays back i deleted that user from db now i am not able access icingaweb2 UI,
Getting below error while trying to access to the [link](http://localhost/icingaweb2).
All configured authentication methods failed. Please check the system log or Icinga Web 2 log for more information.

I followed the below [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-icinga-and-icinga-web-on-ubuntu-16-04) to install icinga2 server

Please Help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolved the issue by re-creatinging a setup token in in the Icinga Web 2  by using bellow command

**sudo icingacli setup token create**
i got some error's while creating setup token and it is easily resolved by using [1]: https://monitoring-portal.org/index.php?thread/40111-icingacli-does-not-work/

Answer (score 0):

If you still have access to the MySQL DB you should do a backup first of your icinga2 DB.

`mysqldump -u [username] -p [password] [databasename] > [backupfile.sql]`

Then purge MySQL or follow the [guide on how to reset your root password](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html)

After you have access to the DB again if you purged MySQL use this to bring your data back in.

`mysqldump -u [username] -p [password] [databasename] < [backupfile.sql]`

If you only lost your password to IcingaWeb2 or now have access to MySQL then create a MD5 based BSD password algorithm:

`openssl passwd -1 "password"`

> Note: The switch to `openssl passwd` is the **number one** (`-1`) for using the MD5 based BSD password algorithm.

Insert the user into the database using the generated password hash:

````
INSERT INTO icingaweb_user (name, active, password_hash) VALUES ('icingaadmin', 1, 'hash from openssl');

[Source](https://lists.icinga.org/pipermail/icinga-users/2015-March/009236.html)